# Unable to perform Create, Edit, Delete on Protected Custom Object records in packaging org

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-object, lightning-apps, feature-management

I am trying to understand how the protected custom object works within a package context. With the help of Salesforce support, I was able to enable Feature Management option in the sample packaging org and created a custom object with visibility set to below:

> Only Apex code in the same namespace can see the type. The name of the
> type and the record are visible if they're referenced in a formula.

Using the standard classic screen, I was able to create, edit and delete the records of the protected custom object. In Lightning Experience, I was not able to view the protected object, weirdly it did not even show up in LEX's Object Manager UI.

For our ISV package, it is critical for a custom interface to be able to Read, Create, Edit, and Delete protected object records. So, I created a sample Lightning App to do, and below is what I am seeing:

> 1. I able to query the records and show them in the UI
> 2. Unable to create a new record, edit and delete record.

Below is the exception I get from Apex:

*when sending the JSON instance of the object to Apex and deserializing it*

```
[{"exceptionType":"System.NoAccessException","isUserDefinedException":false,"message":"Insufficient Privileges: You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.","stackTrace":"Class.System.JSON.deserialize: line 15, column 1\nClass.fmass.TestController.insertRecord: line 10, column 1"}]
```

*when sending the instance of the object to Apex as it is*

```
[{"message":"An internal server error has occurred\nError ID: 1160944546-55143 (-152691036)"}]
```

When I tried to do the same in the Apex Anonymous window, I am able to Read, Insert, Update and Delete the protected object records. I even tried to replicate the same Lightning App's code pointing to a normal custom object in the packaging org and everything works fine as expected.

I literally thought a protected custom object would behave the same as a normal object only thing is in the subscriber org, we won't see the object. But the behavior, I am seeing with the protected object is so strange.

Is this how protected objects work or is this a bug in salesforce?

Comment: Please tell me how you got this error “System.NoAccessException”, tell me what steps to see the same?  Also when you refer to “protected objects” do you mean “protected custom settings” objects? BTW as of Jan2021 im noticing that LEX’s setup menu is bugged in that the “manage” link on custom settings is broken in LEX but works fine in Classic

Comment: @PeterNoges I got this error when calling the auraenabled method which contains the dml statement in apex from the lightning app code. It is a protected custom object which was salesforce introduced few releases back and it works with feature management(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/fma_hide_custom_objects_permissions.htm). Here's another link for your reference(https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200591/can-featuremanagement-changeprotection-be-used-to-protect-any-custom-object)

Comment: Hmm, im not sure. Thanks Praveen for the links. Hopefully someone else can answer

Comment: Hi @Praveen were you able to figure this out? I am facing the same issue.